# Angular 6 Binding With .NET Core API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Need one help on which I am working since morning.

What I have done :

1. I am able to bind the list to UI while getting list from Firebase.
2. I am also able to connect with the "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" and bind the list to UI.

Why/where I need your help:

But I don't know why I am not able to bind the list from .NET Core API to Angular 6.

Note:-

1. My API is working and I am sure because I have test it with postman and swagger.
2. Able to hit the API and getting response from .NET Core API but not able to map or bind it to my angular variable which declared as "any" type. Seems like I am not able to fetch the data from the response.

I have tried so many examples but no luck till now. 
Below is the code what I have done in angular 6 project.

**##ToDoService.ts file code**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {environment } from "../../environments/environment"
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ToDoService {
  myAppUrl: string = environment.url;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getToDoList() {
    return this.GetMethod();
  }  

  GetMethod()  : Observable<any> {
    console.log("called");
       var headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

       console.log('calling viju method');
       console.log(headers);
       var result = this._http.get(this.myAppUrl,{headers:headers})
       .map((response: Response) => response.json());

       return result;
  }

}
```

**##ToDoComponent.ts file code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToDoService } from './service/to-do.service'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ToDo';
  ToDolist : any[];
  ToDoForm : FormGroup;
constructor(private _fb : FormBuilder, private _service : ToDoService ){

  this.ToDoForm = this._fb.group({
    ToDoId: 0,
    Content: new FormControl(),
    Status: new FormControl(),
  });

  this.getToDoList();
}

  getToDoList(){
    // debugger;
    this._service.getToDoList()
    .subscribe(res=> this.ToDolist = res);
    debugger;
    console.log(this.ToDolist);
  }
}
```

Please check the below error screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Is the result in `res` available? What is `this.ToDolist`? Is the request successful (see network tab)? You have to show a little bit more than that. – Also, you are using CORS wrong, the `Access-Control-Allow-X` headers are _response_ headers, not request headers.

Comment: This is not related to c# nor to ASP.NET Core. You have a syntax error, you need to check your TypeScript code

Comment: And *WHY* is this being voted down? This is a valid question. Is it just a problem with the title? Then suggest an edit.

Comment: @DeborahK The question is missing crucial information that just invites random guesses as to why the observed problem could be happening. We have no idea where that “SyntaxError” comes from (real syntax errors should be caught at TypeScript-compile time already), or what the response from the API is. We don’t even know what type `_http` is, which would directly help your answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Please check the updated code.

Comment: and why this question are voted down... I have changed the title and give more information for clarification.. now what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the issues identified in the comments ...

If you are using Angular v6, then your Observable imports are not correct. (Unless you are using the backward compatibility library?)

Here are the import statements for RxJS v6:

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

It also appears that you are mixing code for the *old* `Http` and the *new* `HttpClient`.

The old `Http` required the `.json()`. The new `HttpClient` automatically performs the required mapping for you.

My get code looks like this:

```
  getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl);
  }
```

Or with console log and exception handling, like this:

```
  getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Also, since Http calls are asynchronous, you can't console.log them immediately after the call. They will be undefined. You need to move your log within the subscribe.

```
  getToDoList(){
    // debugger;
    this._service.getToDoList()
    .subscribe(res=> {
         this.ToDolist = res;
         debugger;
         console.log(this.ToDolist);
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the non-pure RxJS operators. Sure, piping the new ones is the new recommendation, but the old ones should still work fine.

Comment: @Deborahk I have learned angular 2 from your pluralsight tutorials.. Thanks for your that aweosme tutorial. 

I will try this.. hope it will work..

Comment: Thanks! Be sure to also look at the comments on your original post regarding how you are setting up your headers.

Comment: I also just updated my answer to include the additional issue in your subscribe method.

Comment: @DeborahK Awesome.. in one go it start working... Thanks a lot. 
Can you please help me to get link where I can read the depth of Angular 6.

Comment: I had already. Can you mark my response as your answer to close this question? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your service method name says 'GetMethod'. But in component you are calling getToDoList().

Here is the updated service code.

```
GetMethod()  : Observable<any> {
    console.log("called");
       var headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');


       return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl,{headers:headers})
       .map((response: any) => response.json());
  }
```

Comment: You haven’t changed anything of significance in that method.

Comment: @suresh 

GetMethod again calling from getToDoList().


getToDoList(){

 GetMethod();
}